# Spring Boot/Security predefined set of users - best practices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a requirement, that all users (only about 35) in the Spring-boot application (using JPA with Postgres) should be predefined (e.g. before deployment defined email-password combinations - only password can be changed afterwards, but no new users added).

I am wondering, what are best practices to achieve that. Run the inserts direclty on start of the spring-boot application with a specific profile active? Run a SQL-query? Directly insert those into the database? Or are there other more secure versions to achieve that?

It would be great to have some tips about best practices of such a setting.

Comment: Run a one time script, throw away the script. You dont want any passwords hardcoded anywhere. Version control the database using liquibase or flyway. Take secure database backups.